# Cannot click button in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a page in `HTML` which has a background based on the well-known [particle library](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/). I have a button and there is a problem with it: it can be seen but it cannot be clicked. I tried changing the size and the alignment of the background but cannot make it to work... How to make the button clickable?

My code:
HTML:

```
<div id="particles-js" ><canvas class="particles-js-canvas" width="500" height="1000"></canvas></div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="alert('hello')">Info</button>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #212121;
}

.particles-js-canvas{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

And the `Javascript` code to initialize the particles:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {

    particlesJS("particles-js", {
        "particles": {
            "number": {
                "value": 400,
                "density": {
                    "enable": true,
                    "value_area": 400
                }
            },
            "color": {
                "value": "#ffffff"
            },
            "shape": {
                "type": "circle",
                "stroke": {
                    "width": 0,
                    "color": "#000000"
                },
                "polygon": {
                    "nb_sides": 4
                },
                "image": {
                    "src": "http://wiki.lexisnexis.com/academic/images/f/fb/Itunes_podcast_icon_300.jpg",
                    "width": 100,
                    "height": 100
                }
            },
            "opacity": {
                "value": 0.5,
                "random": true,
                "anim": {
                    "enable": false,
                    "speed": 1,
                    "opacity_min": 0.1,
                    "sync": false
                }
            },
            "size": {
                "value": 2,
                "random": true,
                "anim": {
                    "enable": false,
                    "speed": 40,
                    "size_min": 0.1,
                    "sync": false
                }
            },
            "line_linked": {
                "enable": false,
                "distance": 150,
                "color": "#ffffff",
                "opacity": 0.4,
                "width": 1
            },
            "move": {
                "enable": true,
                "speed": 1,
                "direction": "bottom",
                "random": false,
                "straight": true,
                "out_mode": "out",
                "bounce": false,
                "attract": {
                    "enable": false,
                    "rotateX": 600,
                    "rotateY": 1200
                }
            }
        },
        "interactivity": {
            "detect_on": "canvas",
            "events": {
                "onhover": {
                    "enable": false,
                    "mode": "grab"
                },
                "onclick": {
                    "enable": false,
                    "mode": "repulse"
                },
                "resize": true
            },
            "modes": {
                "grab": {
                    "distance": 200,
                    "line_linked": {
                        "opacity": 1
                    }
                },
                "bubble": {
                    "distance": 400,
                    "size": 40,
                    "duration": 2,
                    "opacity": 8,
                    "speed": 3
                },
                "repulse": {
                    "distance": 200,
                    "duration": 0.4
                },
                "push": {
                    "particles_nb": 4
                },
                "remove": {
                    "particles_nb": 2
                }
            }
        },
        "retina_detect": true
    });
});
```

Comment: you're missing a ';' when the alert command ends at alert('hello')

Comment: ';' shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: @GuyL tried adding ';' does not work either

Comment: Please, provide a snippet or jsFiddle where we can see and try your code. [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you can see your button, that does not mean that the button is in the foreground. Actually, the canvas is hiding your button. You can try adding a [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to the background:

```
body {
    background: #212121;
}

.particles-js-canvas{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: this works, I thought that it is harder to solve the problem...thank you

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, this is what you need.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="alert('hello'); setLocation('https://example.com');">Info</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a canvas inside a div tag. This canvas hides access to the button and acts as a layer on top of it.

Add this to the CSS code and it takes care of the rest.

```
canvas{
  z-index:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to show an `alert` add `javascript` before alert. Also note inline javascript is not a good practice.Rather you should create a function and avoid using alert as function name since it is window reserved method

```html
<div id="particles-js">
  <canvas class="particles-js-canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="javascript:alert('hello')">Info</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

We are using particles.js canvas as an overlay element. Altering the z-index order in this case doesn't help.
If the on hover, on click, ie. 'grab, repulse, bubbles' interactivity features of particles.js are not required – It's possible to disable pointer events on the canvas via css, this will allow a user to click through the canvas and interact with underlying elements.

`canvas.particles-js-canvas-el {
    pointer-events: none;
}`